# Free bus shuttle service from Hong Kong airport?

Tags: public-transport, buses, airport-transfer, hong-kong, hkg

Does someone have details and the route of the free bus service from/to Hong Kong (HKG) airport to the city ?

Comment: Neither the airport website nor Wikitravel have heard of such a free service. Where did you hear about it?

Comment: @Gilles a relative that has been there 5 years ago

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a free *public* shuttle bus service to/from the airport. (There are, of course, [normal paid public buses that serve HKIA](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/bus_from_hkia.html).) What I think your relative may have gotten it confused with is [complimentary hotel bus services](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/hotel-shuttle-bus-limousine.html) that are reserved for guests.

I'd recommend taking the [HKIA Express](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/airport-express.html) though. It's a lot cheaper ($100) than getting a taxi and a lot faster than a bus given Hong Kong's traffic, and if you're going *to* the airport many airlines now offer check-in desks in the city itself, before you get to the airport.

Once you have paid for your ticket and caught the HKIA express:

> Free shuttle bus service is available, taking passengers from Kowloon or Hong Kong stations to most major hotels and transport interchanges. Passengers can also enjoy free porter service at all Airport Express stations.

So if you have a hotel near Kowloon or Hong Kong station, you should be able to get a free shuttle bus once you have taken the Airport Express.

Comment: is this free?
http://www.mtr.com.hk/eng/getting_around/complom_free_bus.html

Comment: @EladBenda Er, that's not from the airport. If you read it, it says "The Airport Express Shuttle-bus is a complimentary **add-on service provided exclusively for Airport Express passengers** travelling between Hong Kong or Kowloon station and major hotels and railway interchanges." - the Airport Express is the HKIA Express I'm talking about. THAT bus service operates from Hong City / Kowloon end of the HKIA Express. And if you're already within the city, you might as well use their subway / "MTR", it's not expensive.

Comment: I sorry for asking again, but I didn't understand. 'Airport Express passengers' is this the small east (domestic?) airport?

Can you show me pins on Google maps?

Comment: Hong Kong has only one international airport, and as far as I'm aware, no public domestic airport. If you look at the [HK MTR system map](http://wikitravel.org/upload/shared//9/96/HK_MTR_System_Map.png) it's the dark green line. So once you get off from the airport express stops in say Kowloon or Hong Kong City, you can catch the shuttle buses from there on, but not at the airport itself.

Comment: Also note the airport express stops in an MTR station (although it's a long walk to the MTR).  Also if you go aboveground there, they have taxis which are generally pretty cheap if you are at all close to where you want to go.

Comment: regrading http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/hotel-shuttle-bus-limousine.html
I have an ibis hotel reservation, can I use this service? btw, can I use this service if i'm future to be guest in some hotel in HKG city?

Comment: @EladBenda I'm not sure whether Ibis offers that service. I'd say go to that hotel transfers desk to see if Ibis is covered, if not, take HKIA Express.

Comment: as I understood from you, Ill take the HKIA anyway and just need to decide where to stop (using the bus service or getting or switching to MTR). btw, is the MTR ride payed according to the ride distance or is it fixed price?

Comment: Ibis will have instructions on its site on how to reach by MTR. Fares are calculated according to distance. However, that itself is a separate question so if you have more on that ask it as a separate question rather than having an extended discussion in comments.